# Laravel Ioc container in out of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a listener in Laravel 5.2.I which depends on `Requests` object instances via `Ioc` container. How can I do that? Say I've created `foo` class that depends on `bar` class in Laravel. How can I get automatic resolution through Laravel `Ioc`?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that any class can be built through the IoC. It can be as simple as

```
$foo = app(Foo::class);
```

This would dependency inject `Bar` if it is type hinted correctly in the constructor of `Foo` AND both `Foo` and `Bar` have no other dependencies that can't be resolved by IoC.

If you have dependencies that can't be resolved by reflection, you will need to let the IoC know how to construct them.